# DateTime listener, listen to the minute changes

Tags: flutter, dart

I want to listen to the minute changes, for example, if it is `6:00`, I want to listen when it is `6:01` and then `6:02`, and so on.

There are two ways (not good enough) that I can think of doing this.

1. I can setup a `Timer.periodic` which runs every second and check for the change in minute.
2. I can setup a `Timer.periodic` which runs every second till the minute gets changed but after that it cancels itself and fires up another `Timer.periodic` which runs every minute.

Is there any better solution than these workarounds?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Just get the current time, compute the duration until the next minute, and set a non-periodic `Timer` for that amount of time.  from there, you can create a periodic timer that runs every minute.

```dart
void executeOnMinute(void Function() callback) {
  var now = DateTime.now();
  var nextMinute =
      DateTime(now.year, now.month, now.day, now.hour, now.minute + 1);
  Timer(nextMinute.difference(now), () {
    Timer.periodic(const Duration(minutes: 1), (timer) {
      callback();
    });

    // Execute the callback on the first minute after the initial time.
    //
    // This should be done *after* registering the periodic [Timer] so that it
    // is unaffected by how long [callback] takes to execute.
    callback();
  });
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to use that listener in a widget, you can use [datetime_loop](https://pub.dev/packages/datetime_loop) package:

```
DateTimeLoopBuilder(
  timeUnit: TimeUnit.minutes,
  builder: (context, dateTime, child) {
    return Column(
      children: [
        Container(
          width: 200,
          height: 200,
          color: Color((math.Random().nextDouble() * 0xFFFFFF).toInt()).withOpacity(1.0),
        ),
        Text('$dateTime'),
      ],
    );
  }
)
```